# Conditionally reverse ASC/DESC sort order in Access SQL with IF ELSE in ORDER BY?

Tags: sorting, ms-access, sql-order-by

I want to sort the table according to two parameters in an Access DB.

If the first parameter is greater than the second parameter, table should sort in ascending order or vice-versa.

Comment: And those parameters come from where? Edit question to show example data, example desired result, and what you have already tried.

Comment: You had an `Eg:` but I think you forgot to include your example.  (I'll remove the mystery "eg" and a couple relevant tags.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Short Answer:*

This will sort my table by `ID` in **Ascending** order *"if the 1st parameter is greater than the 2nd parameter"*, **otherwise the field is sorted in Descending order**:

```
SELECT ID
FROM mytable
ORDER BY IIf([First Parameter]>[Second Parameter],[id],-[id]);
```

...note that since the [parameters] do not exist in my source table, the user's prompted to enter them:

[image: example]

---

## *Longer Answer:*

We can conditionally reverse the `ASC`/`DESC` sort order of a numeric field simply by **changing it's sign** with a [**`-`**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd#__toc272228348) in an `IIf` (["Immediate If"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/iif-function)) statement in the `ORDER BY` clause, like:

`ORDER BY IIf( {your condition here}, {sort field name} ,-{sort field name} )`

...note the `-` on the "Value if False" expression, which reverses the positive/negative sign on the value of `id`.  We should *not* specify `DESC` (or else "the reversal is reversed").

**For example**, let's say we have a table with only one column: `ID`. We can calculate whether `ID` is "odd" or "even" with an `IIf` statement:

```
IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd")
```

...so if we want to sort my list ***Ascending* on even-numbered days**, and ***Descending* on odd-numbered days**, we can use:

```
SELECT ID
FROM mytable
ORDER BY IIf(day(date())/2=day(date())\2,[id],-[id]);
```

[image: Results]

---

### **More about `IIf` statements in `ORDER BY` clauses:**

In Access SQL, you use can an `IIF` statement in an `ORDER BY` clause just like you would use it in the `SELECT` statement.

If we want return *only* the `ID` field, but sort all the **Even** numbers to the top of the list, the entire SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT ID
FROM myTable
ORDER BY IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd");
```

...on the other hand, if we want that value to be *included* in the query results (with a name of `OddEven`), the `IIf` statement would appear *twice*:

```
SELECT ID, IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd") AS OddEven
FROM myTable
ORDER BY IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd");
```

...or to limit the result to one of the crtieria (and display the field with a name of `OddEven`), we could use:

```
SELECT ID
FROM myTable
WHERE IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd")="Even"
ORDER BY IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd");
```

Of course, the simplest way is usually to just use the Query Designer, and let Access figure out the SQL:

[image: query]

...and finally, if we wanted to display the `OddEven` field *and* limit the results to "Even" records, the `IIf` statement would appear **three** times:

```
SELECT ID, IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd") AS OddEven
FROM mytable
WHERE (((IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd"))="Even"))
ORDER BY IIf([id]/2=[id]\2,"Even","Odd");
```

Comment: This is a great trick. Got anything similar for string?